# With Jmeter, how can we create users using CSV file, if the user already exist in first execution

Tags: jmeter

With Jmeter, how can we create users using CSV file because at CSV it is picking first userid and if re-running the script it will say user already exist.
Please help me to create users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create a new user every time you run the test it doesn't make sense to use CSV files and CSV Data Set Config, I would recommend using following [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) instead:

- [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - returns current timestamp in different formats
- [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - returns a random number in given range
- [__randomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - returns a random string from given characters

You can also use any of above functions as prefix or postfix for username from the CSV file - this way you will get new unique logins each time you will run your test

[image: JMeter Functions for parameterizing]

Answer (score 0):

Abdul, you can concatenate random number using [__Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function in the request where you are passing the userid [picked from the csv file] for creating the user.

For example: Your .csv file contains userid as:
ravi
abdul

Now, in the http request pass the userid picked from the csv file and concatenate __Random function

Example: ${userid}${__Random(1,100000,str_ran)}

Additionally, you can also get the list of userids created in the test run by writing a simple code in [Beanshell Postprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) that can create a separate .txt file with all the userids.

Let me know if you need any further information.

You can get more information on JMeter elements from the [knowledge base](https://www.redline13.com/blog/kb/)